# UIImage from CMSampleBuffer has a blue tint

Tags: ios, swift2, avfoundation, avcapture

I am displaying a video feed of CMSampleBuffers converted to UIImages inside a UIImageView.  In the photo below, the background layer is an AVCapturePreviewLayer and the center is the buffer feed.  My goal is to remove the blue tint.

[image]

Here is the CMSampleBuffer to UIImage code

```
extension CMSampleBuffer {
  func imageRepresentation() -> UIImage? {

    let imageBuffer: CVImageBufferRef = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(self)!

    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0)
    let address = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(imageBuffer, 0)
    let bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer)
    let width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer)
    let height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer)

    let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()

    let context = CGBitmapContextCreate(address, width, height, 8, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, CGImageAlphaInfo.NoneSkipFirst.rawValue)
    let imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context)

    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0)
    let resultImage: UIImage = UIImage(CGImage: imageRef!)

    return resultImage
  }
}
```

AVCaptureVideoDataOutput setup:

```
class MovieRecorder: NSObject {
  // vars
  private let captureVideoDataOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()

  // capture session boilerplate setup...

  captureVideoDataOutput.videoSettings = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey: Int(kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)]
  captureVideoDataOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true
  captureVideoDataOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: captureDataOutputQueue)
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was with the bitmapInfo.  This bitmap info fixed it.

```
let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.NoneSkipFirst.rawValue | CGBitmapInfo.ByteOrder32Little.rawValue)
let context = CGBitmapContextCreate(address, width, height, 8, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, bitmapInfo.rawValue)
```